# vue.js captue event bus from component to another component

Tags: vue.js, emit

I have 2 vue.js components Like componentA、componentB

I want to put componentB in componentA , I want emit my custom event from componentB to componentA .
But I call this.$emit('updateStartTimeEvent')  at componentB , But componentA don't capture this event , How can I do .
My Source Code Sample Like below :

componentA.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <componentB  v:on:updateStartTimeEvent="updateStartTime"   dateRangeSelector="dateRangeSelector" startTime="start_time" endTime="start_time"  ></componentB>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import componentB from '../componentB.vue';
    export default {
         components: {
           componentB
        },
        data () {
            return {
                dateRangeSelector: 'one',
                start_time: '',
                end_time: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateStartTime: function(startTime) {
                console.log(startTime);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

And CompoentB.vue Like :

```
<template>
    <div id="CompoentB">
        <input type="button" @click="toggleDateRang('me')">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['dateRangeSelector', 'startTime' , 'endTime'],
        methods: {
            toggleDateRang: function(which) {
                this.$emit('updateDateRangeSelectorEvent', which);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not `v:on` its `v-on`.

Comment: For non parent-child communication, you can use another Vue instance as a dedicated event bus. [The official documentation touches on this.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

Comment: @miqid It's directly parent child. No bus is needed. Here is a working version. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MOGQMN?editors=1010